# Is it possible to change or destroy goods that a scout is sending?

Tags: civilization-board-game

In the rulebook of Civilization (p.26) it says that

> The player declares which of their cities the scout is "sending" the
>   square to during the Start of Turn Phase, and all the icons in that
>   square (including trade, production, culture, coins and resources) are
>   then considered to in that city's outskirts for the rest of the turn.

**Is it possible to disturb the acquisition of the "icons"? (or to change the icons?)**

---

I'll give you some examples, when you might get into thinking of this question

**1) The scout is moved**

The scout might be moved by a culture card, such as *Disoriented*, *Lost* or *Out of Position* (Played in the City Management Phase). Will the scout still send the "original" icons, or are the icons changed?

**2) The square is changed**

**a)** .. by a culture event card:

*Drought* (Played at the Start of Turn Phase) would make the square a desert square (One trade icon on it). Would the scout send the original icons, or would you get the trade at the trade phase?

*Deforestration* (Played at the Start of Turn Phase) can be used to make a square a grassland square.

*Flooding* (Played at the Start of Turn Phase) can be used to make a square a water square.

*Sabotage*, *Catastrophe* or *Disaster* (Player at the Start of Turn Phase) can be used to destroy a building. If the scout was on a building, would it be sending the icons on the building, or on the square below the building?

**b)**.. or by a technology

*Gunpowder* (City Management Phase) can be used to destroy a building or ancient wonder.

**c)** .. or by a player action

If the scout is in outskirts of another player, and that player builds a building/wonder/great person on it. Will the player with the scout receive the original or the new icons?

Also, the scout might be in the outskirts of a city A, and a player might want to have more hammers in his another city (city B). Now, if he builds a building/great person with hammers below the scout, will the scout send these new hammer icons to the city B (or the icons below the new tile, assuming that the scout is paired with the city B)?

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ 2.0](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/news/Civilization%20FAQ_v2.0.pdf), page 2, we have the following:

> Q: Can a scout gather icons and/or resources from a square  in another
>   city’s outskirts? What if the square contains a  building or a wonder?
>
> A: A scout can gather resources from a square in another city’s 
>   outskirts, even if that square contains a building or wonder. If  the
>   scout sends those icons and resources to a different city,  the
>   original city cannot also use those icons and resources.

---

> Q: When a scout moves into or out of a square with a coin  icon, is
>   the coin total updated immediately?
>
> A: Yes. This can result in an economic victory.

Given this, it appears that two things are true.  First, when a scout moves, the tile it is sending to the city also updates (as evidenced by the coin example).  Second, if a scout is on a tile of one city, the resources from that tile can be routed to a different city or not, but cannot be double counted.

It would appear from this that the behavior of the scout is to have the tile it is on considered part of a city of your choice.  If the scout moves, the resources it is sending are changed to the scout's new location.  If the tile the scout is on is modified, the resources the scout is sending also update (exactly the same as if that tile were in the city radius of the city the scout is sending resources to).